Determinant and trace of a linear transformation
Let $V=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be the space of polynomials in x,y with complex coefficient. And $H_{n}(x,y)$ be the subspace of homogeneous polynomial of degree n,i.e. $Span_{\mathbb{C}}\{x^iy^{n-i}|0\leq i\leq n\}$

Check that V is a vector space.
Suppose $g=\begin{bmatrix}
                a&b\\
                c&d
            \end{bmatrix} 
$ Prove that $\{(ax+cy)^{i}(bx+dy)^{n-i}\}$ is a basis of
$H_{n}(x,y)$ iff $det(g)\neq0$.
Consider the map
$T_{g}:H_{n}(x,y)\xrightarrow {}H_{n}(x,y)$. by
$T_{g}(f)=f(ax+cy,bx+dy)$ compute $det(T_g)$ and $Tr(T_g)$ in terms
of the eigenvalues of g.

I can finish Q1 and Q2. Q1 is just checking the definition. For Q2, we consider the map given in Q3; the map $T_{g}$ is invertible iff $det(g)\neq 0$, and the inverse map is just $T_{g^{-1}}$ ;so it map basis to basis. But I am now stuck in Q3; I only know that the determinant and trace of $T_{g}$ is the product and sum of eigenvalues of $T_{g}$ respectively. But I cannot find the eigenvalue of $T_{g}$ in terms of the eigenvalue of g.

Hint: have you dealt with the case when $g$ is diagonal? Hint 2: can you prove that if $g_1,g_2$ are similar then $T_{g_1}, T_{g_2}$ are similar?

@ancient mathematician Many thanks!! It is very clear

Good. Maybe you should write an answer yourself then.
